# Measuring time between 2 points of various microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, metrics

Example:
We have 2 microservices (A, B) and queue (Q).

A receives request from client, **process** this request and sends message to Q
B receives message from Q **process** this message and saving some stuff to database.

I want to measure time between these points (including time when message is waiting on queue):

- application A is starting to process request
- application B is ending processing message

There are any ready solution for collecting that metrics? (It would be nice if it was easily integrative with spring-boot)

Comment: Check out [Micrometer](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector), it may give you what you want.

Comment: Maybe you should look at this https://www.jaegertracing.io. With it you can measure time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy/fast way: just log the events you are interested in, and make the time difference.

The professional/right way: integrate a metric system with your spring-boot application. This requires some effort, but the benefits are much bigger.

Here are the steps:

- Document about [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/), [Grafana](https://grafana.com/)
- Follow [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator-metrics-monitoring-dashboard-prometheus-grafana/) step-by-step guide which shows you how to integrate those components and add your own custom metric
- Add your own metrics and create dashboards (in other words, build your observability setup, because you already got all the components in place)